# How to persist request data after request

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp

I am using JSPs. I have this use case:

The homepage contains a searchbox ,a submit button and a dropdown. After a user selects something from dropdown, enters a query in a searchbox and hit submit button, it goes to the same page with some results based on query.

Home page includes other pages(say results.jsp, searchtables.jsp ) which are visible only after the search returns some result. I want to persist the values entered in the home page(dropdown and searhcbox) after these results are shown.

So if homepage is /home , after the button is clicked, it is still in the same page with /search appended to it and it shows the results retrieved.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the request attribute in the controller if you are using forward not redirect:

```
request.setAttribute("searchVal", searchVal); 
request.setAttribute("dropdownVal", dropdownVal);
```

And then on the jsp page you can access the value like this:

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="${searchVal}"/> //will be empty if searchVal is never set


<select>
    <option value="val1" ${dropdownVal == 'val1' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>val1</option>
</select>
```

If you are doing redirect, you can either append the values as the url query and then access them using `${params.search}` and `${params.dropdown}` on the jsp page.

The last option is to use localStorage in [HTML5 web storage objects](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) which is storing things on client side instead of server side but you will need to write some javascript codes to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the form is submitting to itself, you can check the post parameters and if they exist, add them to your form.

```
<input type="text" name="txtbox" value="<%= request.getParameter("txtbox") %>">
```

You can then do something similar with the drop down values an add "selected" to the option if that was the item that was passed via POST

```
<select name="mySelect">
    <option value="1" <% if(request.getParameter("mySelect") == "1"){ out.print("selected") } %>>Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" <% if(request.getParameter("mySelect") == "2"){ out.print("selected") } %>>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Isn't it a bad idea to use java code inside jsp?

also I did not get how to add "selected option" in the post?

Comment: I made some changes to my example that should simplify the textbox example and I added an example for the drop down as well.